# Identify Error in XSD format

Tags: xml, xsd

I am facing an error while validating an XML file. The error says

> SCHEMA NOT FOUND

So I figured out where the problem is in the XSD file.

When I remove this code from XSD file it is working, but I didn't find the actual problem why it works after removing this code. Can anybody help me out on that?

```
<xs:complexType name="Date-Format">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>DTM</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:element name="DateTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:element name="Days">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>To indicate a quantity of days</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="3"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Weeks">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>To indicate a quantity of weeks</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="3"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Months">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>To indicate a quantity of months</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="3"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Years">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>To indicate a quantity of years</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="3"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. It may be of course that it's wrong in the context of the larger schema (for example, there might be duplicate declarations) but we can't be expected to see that.

The error message "schema not found" suggests that the system couldn't find the schema, not that a portion of your schema was incorrect. What led you to think that removing this part of the schema would fix the problem?

Frankly, I think it's unlikely that the system actually produced the error message "SCHEMA NOT FOUND". Who produces all-caps error messages these days? I think it's more likely that you've given your personal interpretation of what you think the error message means. Don't do that: you might not understand the error message, but other people will.

Comment: I was using this... so I reduced code and reuploaded it many times. and found that when I am not using XSD with this piece of code. it works.. sounds awkward but it is happening

Comment: If you want help from others to resolve your problem, you need to provide enough material so others can reproduce your problem. So you need to provide your full schema and instance document, and to say how you ran the validation.